# Database table showing multiple results per field

Tags: sql

Attempting to form a query using 2 tables involving member of a cycling club and their respective place in a race with Microsoft Access.  When I attempt to run the following SQL code I get a query table that displays every RaceID and Member, but doesn't link each member to 1 place per race.

```
SELECT RaceID, LastName, FirstName, Place
FROM Members, RaceResults;
```

What I do wind up with is a listing for every member of the club in all places (1-10) in every race.  I have attempted to do both a count function per raceID and a Join function to combine the memberID's between both tables.  Neither seem to either work, or have the same result as my current table.  I would appreciate any suggestions on what I am missing in my SQL Query to properly display my table.

Comment: Well, that's because you are simply doing a cartesian product between both tables. What are the columns of each table?, how do they need to be joined (which column do they have in common)?. What is your actual desired result?

Comment: Add the connection between the tables in the WHERE: WHERE Members.something = RaceResults.somethingElse

Answer (score 0):

When you join the result of 2 tables, you need to tell the database how they are linked, otherwise you'll get a cartesian product of both tables,.

Example:

```
SELECT t.RaceID, t.LastName, t.FirstName, tt.Place
FROM Members t join  RaceResults tt on (t.RaceId = tt.RaceId);
```